Symfony Use Mercure with RabbitMQ ? Possible?
I would like to use mercure with rabbitmq, use rabbitmq instead of mercury hub. Is this possible ? Maybe in Async
I tried this little code but it doesn't work
My controller

 $update = new Update(
    'https://example.com/books/1',
    json_encode(['status' => 'OutOfStock'])
 );

$bus->dispatch($update);

Messenger.yaml :
        routing:
            Symfony\Component\Mercure\Update: async

Twig :

{% block javascripts %}
<script>
const eventSource = new EventSource("{{ mercure('https://example.com/books/1')|escape('js') }}");
eventSource.onmessage = event => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(event.data));
}
</script>
{% endblock %}

Error in browser console :
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost/home' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
Thanks for your help
